# mocking a function call

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Using Spock framework for java unit testing.
When unit testing a method method1() and method1 is calling a method method2(),In method2() having a code statement as below :

```
Config config = new Config();  
TimeZone tz=TimeZone.getTimeZone(config.getProps().getProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE));
```

The call `config.getProps().getProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE)`

returns `America/Cambridge_Bay`

In getProps method the property files is fetched from weblogic domain and it will not be available in spcok, its taking path as null.

Please suggest how can this function call be mocked in spock.

Comment: Can you actually come up with a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

We can use meta class injection to mock response method2 in unit testing given block. Here ClassName is the class to which method2 belongs to.

```
ClassName.metaClass.method2 = { inputParameters ->
        return "America/Cambridge_Bay"
    }
```

Also it is advisable to use `@ConfineMetaClass([ClassName])` annotation on the unit test to confine the meta class injection changes to your test case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with an example which simulates your situation:

```
class Config {
    Properties getProps() {
        def props = new Properties()

        props.setProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE, 'America/Cambridge_Bay')
        props
    }
}

class Constants {
    static String SERVER_TIMEZONE = 'TIMEZONE'
}

Config config = new Config()

def timeZoneID = config.getProps().getProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE)
def tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID)
assert tz.ID == 'America/Cambridge_Bay'
```

Since method2() doesn't get a *Config* instance injected into it, mocks are out of the question. So we'll use Groovy's metaClass, at the class level (since instance level is out of the question too, for the same reason). You can override *Config.getProps()* like this:

```
Config.metaClass.getProps {
    def props = new Properties()

    props.setProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE, 'Etc/UTC')
    props
}
```

So you can write your Spock test roughly like this:

```
// import Constants
// import Config class

class FooSpec extends Specification {

  @ConfineMetaClassChanges
  def "test stuff"() {
    when:
    Config.metaClass.getProps {
        def props = new Properties()

        props.setProperty(Constants.SERVER_TIMEZONE, 'America/Cambridge_Bay')
        props
    }

    // Do more stuff

    then:
    // Check results
  }  
}
```

## PS

If you can modify method2() to have Config injected, that would be preferable since then you can use Groovy's MockFor.